# How to type Python mixin with superclass calls?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

I'm trying to use the [`FieldMixin` from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47120048/96588) in my project, but I'm having trouble getting it to pass `mypy` checks. The current code:

```
class DynamicFieldsMixin(Serializer):
    context: Dict[str, Any]

    def get_field_names(
        self, declared_fields: OrderedDict, info: FieldInfo
    ) -> Set[str]:
        field_names: Set[str] = self.context.get(
            "fields",
            super().get_field_names(declared_fields, info)
        )
        return field_names
```

Inheriting from `rest_framework.serializers.Serializer` seems weird, and I wonder if there's a way to avoid that, since it's meant to be mixed into actual `Serializer` classes. Just removing the superclass results in this error:

> error: "get_field_names" undefined in superclass

`mypy` configuration:

```
[mypy]
check_untyped_defs = true
disallow_untyped_defs = true
ignore_missing_imports = true
no_implicit_optional = true
warn_redundant_casts = true
warn_return_any = true
warn_unused_ignores = true
```

Comment: Seems like `mypy` should just ignore `super`, since the interface of its return value is inherently determined at runtime, not statically.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can introduce the base class for the sake of type checking only:

```
import typing
from typing import Any, Dict, List, Mapping, TypeVar
from rest_framework.fields import Field
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer
from rest_framework.utils.model_meta import FieldInfo


if typing.TYPE_CHECKING:
    _Base = ModelSerializer
else:
    _Base = object


class DynamicFieldsMixin(_Base):
    context: Dict[str, Any]

    def get_field_names(self, declared_fields: Mapping[str, Field], info: FieldInfo) -> List[str]:
        field_names = super().get_field_names(declared_fields, info)
        # Revealed type is 'builtins.list[builtins.str]'
        reveal_type(field_names)
        return field_names
```

Comment: This causes "error: Invalid base class" when validating.

Comment: Interestingly I get the same error if I simply pull out the parent class name as a variable, with no conditional!

Comment: I've [reported](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/2477#issuecomment-510676044) the failure; let's see if there's a solution in place.

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue. `pip install mypy djangorestframework-stubs` in a new venv, validation of the code from the answer with your config or just `--strict` succeeds with `mypy==0.701` and `mypy==0.711`. I guess the error you get has more puzzle pieces, maybe context-specific? If your project is public, can you share the link to its source code?

Comment: BTW tested with Python 3.6.8 on Linux if that matters.